# WordPress get posts to show on home.php

Tags: wordpress, loops

Is it possible to have the loop display posts on `home.php`? I want to have a static front page using `front-page.php` and then have the loop show posts on `home.php`. I put a link to `home.php` however, it is not showing posts and it is pulling up the index page as well. I thought `home.php` took precedence for showing blog posts. The only way I can get posts to show up on another page is by using the dashboard and setting reading preferences. Is there a way to avoid this so a user that downloads my theme won't have to change reading preferences for the theme to work as designed?

Answer (score 0):

create a custom function for fetching post in the function.php file and then display it through shortcode in any home or front-page file.